# Redirect with CNAME does not work

Tags: domain-name-system

I try to redirect with CNAME DNS entry.

```
www.example.com -> othersite.com
```

when I type [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
I receive a "File not found" error.
There is a file: othersite.com/index.html
What file the message refers to?

Answer (score 6):

A `CNAME` record in DNS is not an HTTP redirect, it's an alias within DNS itself.

Ie, in your example it makes it so that a query for `www.example.com` will resolve the same as a query for `othersite.com` does.

In your example, that would leave a visitor still at `http://www.example.com/`, connecting to whatever IP address is associated with the name `othersite.com`.

If the web server hosting `othersite.com` does not like the `Host: www.example.com` HTTP header, it may well return an error or some default page instead of the content it would serve for `Host: othersite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your dns configuration with dig or nslookup (anoymized)

You can also do a curl, then you see exactly what http does

```
curl -v https://www.site123.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache(whatever)'s virtualhost should include `othersite.com` to accept this new domain ( as this is the domain that is pointing/accessing your server )

Place it under `ServerAlias othersite.com` (i.e) but this is a web server issue not a DNS issue